# Will the virtualisation feature of Windows 8, be compatible with VMware images?

Tags: virtualization, windows-8-preview

Will the virtualisation feature of Windows 8, be compatible with VMware images? Will I able use my `.vmx` images or `.vmdk` hard disks there?

Comment: Just Curious, and I know windows 8 is in beta phase. Still I would like to know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> McLaws said the new Hyper-V includes a number of new storage, memory and networking enhancements. It includes support for a new **.VHDX** virtual hard-drvie format, he added, as well as support for more than four cores.

*(boldness edited in by me, typos copied)*

[Microsoft's Windows 8 client to include a hypervisor for virtualization](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsofts-windows-8-client-to-include-a-hypervisor-for-virtualization/9747)

As Hortinstein pointed out, I bet there will be a community tool to convert the images.

Comment: A better source would be Microsoft's Building Windows 8 blog. Here is a blog straight from MS that talk about Win8 with Hyper-V built-in for client version of Win8. - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/07/bringing-hyper-v-to-windows-8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is pure speculation (...anything about Windows 8 is likely to be at this point) but  Microsoft always seems to favor the use of its own propietary document formats.  You may be able to convert an image over with a community tool or VMware may include an option to export as a Windows image, but I find it very unlikely that the two competitors have much to gain by making their images play nicely with each other.

There is no true standard for Virtual Media, and unless something changes drastically, I still think there will be various camps for VMware, Paralells, VirtualBox, and Microsoft's offering.